Sqlite triggers Execution - Result: no such column: OLD.*
i'm create:
CREATE TABLE "main" (
    "pubKey"    blob,
    "age"   integer,
    PRIMARY KEY("pubKey")
);

CREATE TABLE "mainCount" (
    "age"   integer,
    "count_"    Long,
    PRIMARY KEY("age")
);

CREATE TRIGGER bulk_insert_main
BEFORE INSERT ON main
WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT pubKey FROM main WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO mainCount (age, count_) VALUES (NEW.age, 1);
END

CREATE TRIGGER bulk_update_main
BEFORE INSERT ON main
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT pubKey FROM main WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey AND age + 0 < NEW.age + 0)
BEGIN
  UPDATE main
    SET (age) = (NEW.age)
    WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey;
  INSERT INTO mainCount (age, count_) VALUES (OLD.age, -1); 
  INSERT INTO mainCount (age, count_) VALUES (NEW.age, 1);
  SELECT raise(IGNORE);
END

CREATE TRIGGER bulk_ignore_main
BEFORE INSERT ON main
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT pubKey FROM main WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey AND age + 0 >= NEW.age + 0)
BEGIN
  SELECT raise(IGNORE);
END

CREATE TRIGGER bulk_update_mainCount
BEFORE INSERT ON mainCount
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mainCount WHERE age = NEW.age)
BEGIN
  UPDATE mainCount
    SET (count_) = (count_ + NEW.count_)
    WHERE age = NEW.age;
  SELECT raise(IGNORE);
END

then, when i try insert INSERT, i have error:

Execution finished with errors.
Result: no such column: OLD.age
At line 1:
INSERT INTO main (pubKey, age) VALUES (1, 1)

so, if i delete "INSERT INTO mainCount (age, count_) VALUES (OLD.age, -1);" from TRIGGER bulk_update_main
i'm does't have any error...
what am i doing wrong in this trigger?

OLD references on not valid on insert statements. See the docs

@Mark Benningfield
I got it, thanks! i'm just need to move OLD to the new main update trigger

just move OLD to the new main update trigger:
CREATE TRIGGER bulk_new_update_main
BEFORE UPDATE ON main
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO mainCount (age, count_) VALUES (OLD.age, -1); 
END


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
